# Is Shor's algorithm for factoring still efficient in the presence of small phase noise

Tags: fourier-transform, quantum-computer, algorithms

Quantum Fourier transform of $|a\rangle\in H_N$
$$|a\rangle\longrightarrow\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}e^{\frac{i2\pi a l}{N}}|l\rangle$$
where $N=2^n$ and $H_N$ is $N$-dimensional Hilbert space.

The implementation of this transform would require conditional phase gates some of which introduce an exponentially small phase $\big(e^{i2\pi k/2^n}, k<<2^n\big)$ to a qubit in the ideal case. However, when phase noise (bounded by $e^{i2\pi\epsilon})$ is taken in to consideration, no matter how small $\epsilon$ is, when we are transforming over large enough space those conditional phase gates satisfying $k/2^n<\epsilon$ becomes meaningless.

So phase noise will make Shor's algorithm inefficient when factoring too large integers?